# Can someone explain how to use CANBUS protocol?

Tags: can-bus

I'm trying to use a micro-controller board to talk to an external device using CAN-BUS. But right now, I don't understand the mechanism of CAN-BUS so clearly and how to use it on my hardware.

From what I understand, it's a bus line where multiple devices can broadcast their messages and the priority is determined by the ID of each node.

Can someone tell me what else I'm supposed to be aware of in order to finish my task?

Thanks,
Zhuhan

Answer (score 7):

Ok I'll try to give you some hint but the subject is quite wide.
Yes the CANBus is a broadcast communication where is not important who is sending a message but the message itself. Is let say a Information-centric communication. So usually more than a single message, the important thing is the whole "CAN Database". In such systems (a car for example) is not strictly necessary to know who is sending Air Temperature but it is important to know that Air Temperature is on a certain Frame Id with a certain encoding and cycle time.

Is not even important who is the receiver of the signal but you can decide to add another piece of hardware that needs Air Temperature without re-configuring the communication.

Every CAN Device that share the same bus can send without an arbitration. The arbitration is embedded in the hardware layer. In CAN, the two bits are called Dominant and Recessive. The '0' bit is dominant and the '1' bit is recessive. This means that if two different devices start "talking" at the same time both with the first bit at 0, both keep sending and on the bus you see '0'. Once one device wants to send 1 (a recessive bit) while another is sending a '0' (dominant) the whole bus stay at 0. The sender of the '1' can detect it and stop sending leaving the bus for the winner. Since every CAN frame, after a preamble, starts with ID, lowest ID (with lot o zeros inside) are the one that will win in a collision and will keep the usage of the bus.

Thus the priority is given by ID, the information is bound to an ID, so there is a sort of priority in data.

Normally, when you design CAN application you already have a database to follow, but (as in my case) you have to design a whole system from scratch, you have to perform this analysis and create the database first.

In almost all CAN Controllers there is the possibility to set reception filters and mask. When you design hardware (or better firmware), first common mistake for a beginner is to leave reception filters and mask wide open. This, in a heavy loaded bus can lead to overrun of the reception (callback or interrupt) of the receiving micro.

Other hints about controller configuration controller timing. A CAN bit is divided in a number of time quanta (eg 16). In most controllers you need to select how and when you want to sample the bit to see if it is 0 or 1. Normally you can do it once (single sample point) or more than once (but I never seen more than 3 sample point).

Other things to take into account are the behavior in case of Bus Off or Bus Heavy events or other errors that can occur (find a list of possible CAN Error). I mean that normally there should be the possibility to auto restart the controller in case of bus errors.

There is much more but probably you need to ask something more precise.